# finding similarity within data using grepl

Tags: r

I have a large data frame like this:

```
df
id product
1  milk
2  200
3  gr.
4  Low
5  fat
6  milkshake
7  200
8  gr.
9  High
10 fat
...
```

for each word I need to understand which words are similar to it, I used grepl and I can do this for each word alone but I do not know how to apply it for the whole data frame.

```
matches1<-paste(grepl(words_unlist[1],words_unlist))
matches1<- as.data.frame(matches1)

id matches1
1  1
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  0
6  1
7  0
8  0
9  0
10 0
```

but I need to do the same for all of the words. like this:

```
df
id product     matches1   matches2   matches3   ... matches10
1  milk        1          0          0          ... 0
2  200         0          1          0          ... 0
3  gr.         0          0          1          ... 0
4  Low         0          0          0          ... 0
5  fat         0          0          0          ... 1
6  milkshake   1          0          0          ... 0
7  200         0          1          0          ... 0
8  gr.         0          0          1          ... 0
9  High        0          0          0          ... 0
10 fat         0          0          0          ... 1
...
```

Comment: How is `cheese` similar to `milk` on row 6?

Comment: sorry tmfmnk, I edit it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sapply` and match every `product` with the entire column `df$Product` with `grepl`

```
df[paste0("matches", seq_len(nrow(df)))] <- +(sapply(df$product, grepl, df$product))

df
#   id   product matches1 matches2 matches3 matches4 matches5 matches6 matches7 matches8 matches9 matches10
#1   1      milk        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0         0
#2   2       200        0        1        0        0        0        0        1        0        0         0
#3   3       gr.        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        1        0         0
#4   4       Low        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0         0
#5   5       fat        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0         1
#6   6 milkshake        1        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0         0
#7   7       200        0        1        0        0        0        0        1        0        0         0
#8   8       gr.        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        1        0         0
#9   9      High        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1         0
#10 10       fat        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0         1
```

Comment: It seems that `milk` is not matching `milkshake`.

Comment: @tmfmnk I think `milk` is matching `milkshake` (col `matches1` row 6) but `milkshake` does not match `milk` which I think what OP wants based on their attempt ?

Comment: You are right, it is the other way around. It's hard to tell, I had the impression that the OP wants both of it. Should clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `lapply`

```
df[paste0("matches", seq_len(nrow(df)))] <- +(do.call(cbind, 
              lapply(df$product, grepl, df$product)))
df
#   id   product matches1 matches2 matches3 matches4 matches5 matches6 matches7 matches8 matches9 matches10
#1   1      milk        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0         0
#2   2       200        0        1        0        0        0        0        1        0        0         0
#3   3       gr.        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        1        0         0
#4   4       Low        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0         0
#5   5       fat        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0         1
#6   6 milkshake        1        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0         0
#7   7       200        0        1        0        0        0        0        1        0        0         0
#8   8       gr.        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        1        0         0
#9   9      High        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1         0
#10 10       fat        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0         1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(similar = map(product, ~  
           str_detect(.x, df$product) %>% 
                     as.integer %>% 
                     as.list %>% 
                      set_names(str_c('matches', seq_len(nrow(df)))) %>% 
                     as_tibble )) %>%
    unnest
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:10, product = c("milk", "200", "gr.", "Low", 
  "fat", "milkshake", "200", "gr.", "High", "fat")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```